# How to add Vuepress on a Nuxt project in a proper way?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuepress

I have my Nuxt app and I'm trying to add Vuepress on it. 
I did `yarn add vuepress@next -D` then created the `docs` folder and a `readme.md` file in there.

**The problem:** The project only shows the sidebar and navbar if the `.vuepress` folder is *outside of the `docs` folder*; If it's inside, it won't work - Not respecting the config.js rules.

Also, it's recognising the readme.md from the Nuxt app (outside from docs folder too), not the one inside docs folder.

Can anyone help me with that?

Another question, if this above works, Am I be able to access through `localhost:3000/docs` instead of `localhost:3000`  for the Nuxt project and `localhost:8080` for the docs?

That's my current folder structure (no sidebar showing - not respecting the config.js inside the .vuepress folder):

```
docs
  |__.vuepress
  |     |__config.js
  |
  |__guides
```

The config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  title: 'Documentation',
  description: 'Documentation',
  themeConfig: {
    sidebar: 'auto',
    nav: [{
        text: 'Home',
        link: '/'
      },
      {
        text: 'Guides A',
        link: '/guides/apis/'
      },
      {
        text: 'item with subitems',
        items: [{
            text: 'Subitem 01',
            link: '/'
          },
          {
            text: 'SubItem 02',
            link: '/'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'External',
        link: 'https://google.com'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Vuepress version 1.0.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need to use both of these? If you using Nuxt you don't actually need VuePress. Check the official [VuePress documentation](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/#why-not).

> **Nuxt**
>
> *Nuxt is capable of doing what VuePress does, but it is designed for building applications. VuePress is focused on content-centric static sites and provides features tailored for technical documentation out of the box.*

Comment: I do need it as the Vuepress Docs will be written on NetliftCMS by a few more users. That's why my main Nuxt application will have a Vuepress Documentation.

Comment: @FabioZanchi Since your use-case is funky, there won't be a proper way

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm gonna create a separated project for the docs.